# “ImportError: No module named sendgrid” for SendGrid in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sendgrid

I followed the instruction from the https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendgrid?hl=en and added SendGrid email support to my project.

It works perfectly on the development server but when I deploy to GAE I get “ImportError: No module named sendgrid”

I know the files are on the server (I downloaded source back from GAE to test it) and I have other third party libraries that work but not the sendgrid.

I spoke to SendGrid tech support but they point back to Google.

Here is the import line from main.py

```
from sendgrid import SendGridClient, Mail
```

The project directory structure looks like this:

```
-+
 |
 +sendgrid
 +smtpapi
 main.py
```

UPDATE:

After deleting everything and adding it back bit by bit I've finally discovered what was wrong.

I had a folder for static content called "s". I didn't mentioned it because I thought it was irrelevant. After deleting this folder - sendgrid suddenly started to work. Eventually, I've changed "s" to a longer name that does not starts with "s" and problem has disappeared.

Comment: Show us your import line and your directory structure.

Comment: @Kekito - I've updated the description with information you've asked.

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` in that sendgrid folder?

Comment: Yes `__init__.py` is there. As I mentioned, it works locally on the development server. It feels like GAE is "ignoring" the sendgrid folder. Could it be because sendgrid references some libraries (e.g. sockets) that may not be supported by GAE?

Comment: I'm stumped.  Are you sure that you are not mixing up versions?  Maybe you uploaded sendgrid in one version but you are running another version that doesn't have it?

Comment: The obvious next step is to print your python path (`sys.path`) when in production to determine whether App Engine is adding arbitrary folders it finds in the root-level with `__init__.py`'s (I don't think it does). You may need to augment `sys.path` in your [`appengine_config.py`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig#Python_Module_Configuration) file, either directly or using [`google.appengine.ext.vendor`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27).

Comment: Thanks, I actually found what was wrong eventually. I had a folder for static content called "s" which I didn't mention in the question because I thought it was irrelevant. After I renamed this folder everything started to work.

Comment: That is... extremely weird. Anyways, I guess you can post that as an answer and self-close this question, although if you can manage to figure out *why* that fixed it, that would be better.

Answer (score 4):

install the sendgrid module in ur virtual environment using the following command

```
pip install sendgrid
```

or else u can install it as system wide module by typing

```
sudo apt-get install sendgrid
```

see how I solved it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a folder for static content called "s" which I didn't mention in the question because I thought it was irrelevant. After I renamed this folder everything started to work. So the issue has been resolved, however the cause of it still remains a mystery ...

Answer (score -1):

```
pip install sendgrid
```

Collecting sendgrid
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/c6/d1ff0214c758d49bbc4b3761dae6d5653c3aea801ba49a9c94cc1fbf7980/sendgrid-6.4.7-py3-none-any.whl (73kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 952kB/s
Collecting starkbank-ecdsa>=1.0.0 (from sendgrid)
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4c/48/29de0f3876d8f89906372da49f132e5c5e46e2fa601a198a9eca6402f646/starkbank-ecdsa-1.1.0.tar.gz
Collecting python-http-client>=3.2.1 (from sendgrid)
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d9/93/fffa7a16e735ae8b946a58e2521e71180803440edc2a0de0d2e9d4a93b84/python_http_client-3.3.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: starkbank-ecdsa, python-http-client, sendgrid
Running setup.py install for starkbank-ecdsa ... done
Running setup.py install for python-http-client ... done
Successfully installed python-http-client-3.3.1 sendgrid-6.4.7 starkbank-ecdsa-1.1.0
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 20.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.